# Проблема при упаковке потока с помощью GZipStream - на выходе получается пустой поток

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Код считывает файлы с диска, упаковывает их и пишет в блоб-поле в БД.

Некоторые файлы проходят без проблем, а на некоторых наблюдается следующее:
после упаковки размер стрима равен 10 байт (хотя источник например 11 килобайт).
При попытке распаковать такой стрим он распаковывается в нулевой (длина равна нулю), никаких исключений не возникает.

код упаковки:

```
    public void CompressFrom(Stream src) // src.Lenth == 11900
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
        {
            src.Position = 0;
            src.CopyTo(gz);
            Data = ms.ToArray(); // ms.Length == 10 ! WTF?!
        }
    }
```

На входе FileStream.
И при этом часть файлов запаковывается совершенно нормально, а другая часть - вот так.
Выручайте, сломал всю голову уже )

Comment: `gz.Flush()` пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал. То же самое

Comment: Ну дайте тогда кусок данных для воспроизведения, что ли.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/g-dGF6olevRQE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете немного неправильно. Надо так:

```
public void CompressFrom(Stream src) // src.Lenth == 11900
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // кажется, нужно поменять false на true
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            src.Position = 0;
            src.CopyTo(gz);
        }
        Data = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

[Объяснение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/bclteam/using-a-memorystream-with-gzipstream-lakshan-fernando): `GZipStream` иногда откладывает фактическую запись до того момента, который считает удобным, а до этого просто накапливает данные. (Не исключено, что с новыми данными он захочет паковать уже имеющиеся данные по-другому, поэтому такая стратегия оправдана.) Когда вы закрываете `GZipStream` (а это происходит по выходу из блока), он больше не имеет права откладывать фактическую запись, а значит, данные попадают в целевой `MemoryStream`.

Comment: VladD, спасибо, так сработало. Я правда не понял, почему если перед 
Data = ms.ToArray();
добавить проверку 
if (ms.Length == 10) throw ...
то падает с ошибкой ObjectDisposedException: Доступ к закрытому потоку невозможен
Получается, что GZipStream вызывает Dispose и для выходного потока?

Comment: @yff: В зависимости от флага в конструкторе. Этот самый `true` означает, если я не ошибаюсь, «не закрывать несущий поток» (то есть, в нашем случае `MemoryStream`).

Comment: @VladD Спасибо :-)

Comment: @Glorfindel: You are replacing the link with archive.org, but BCL Team blog is available at docs.microsoft.com (although not under an obvious address).

Comment: @VladD thanks for the ping. I've set up some complicated replacement rules for e.g. Raymond Chen's and Eric Lippert's blogs because they have now index pages per day. For this one, I'd need to check the Wayback Machine copy for the title, and find it in the left sidebar of https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/bclteam/. I guess that's doable, and probably worth it given the sheer amount of broken links (on English Stack Overflow, the script is still fixing links from 2010 (it fixes posts in chronological order))

Comment: @Glorfindel: Ugh, it's a complicated way. Perhaps Microsoft can do us a favor and provide an address upgrade API?